# How do I skip 3 lines when i read a text file

Tags: java

How do I skip 3 lines when i read a text file?  The following only displays the 3rd line. How may I rectify it with the following?

Table values:

```
michelle

98765432

michelle@hotmail.com

22

3

6,7
```

Code:

```
try
        {                           
            String line = null;         
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!(line.startsWith("*")))
                {
                    //reader.readLine();
                    //reader.readLine();
                    //display booking IDs of target customer
                    if (line.equals(String.valueOf(customermobilenumber)))
                    {                                           
                        System.out.println (reader.readLine());
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to skip 3 lines or is skipping it the issue here?

Comment: DO you want to skip the first three lines or skip on some kind of condition?

Comment: i wish to check if the 2nd field is being entered & when so, I skip 4 lines & display the 6th line?

Answer (score 0):

It may seem too stupid a solution, but I got it working after more trial & error:

```
try
        {           
            String line = null;         
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!(line.startsWith("*")))
                {
                    //display booking IDs of target customer
                    if (line.equals(String.valueOf(customermobilenumber)))
                    {               
                        if (reader.readLine() != null )
                        {
                            //skip lines
                            reader.readLine();
                            reader.readLine();
                            System.out.println (reader.readLine());
                        }

                    }
                }
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (line.equals(String.valueOf(customermobilenumber)))
{                                           
    reader.readLine();
    reader.readLine();                        
    System.out.println (reader.readLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
        {                           
            String line = null;         
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // read first line
            {
                if (!(line.startsWith("*")))
                {
                    String ph_no =  reader.readLine();  // read next line (phone number)
                    String email =  reader.readLine();  // read next line (email)
                    //display booking IDs of target customer
                    if (ph_no.equals(String.valueOf(customermobilenumber)))
                    {                                           
                       // sysout(email);
                        sysout(reader.readLine());
                         sysout(reader.readLine());
                         sysout(reader.readLine());


                    }
                }
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!(line.startsWith("*")))
                    {
//Skip line like this. just check after skip whether file ended or not! to avoid null pointer exception.
                        reader.readLine();
                        reader.readLine();
                        reader.readLine();
                        //display booking IDs of target customer
                        if (line.equals(String.valueOf(customermobilenumber)))
                        {   
                           //use null pointer check here.
                           if(reader.readLine != null)
                           {                                        
                            System.out.println (reader.readLine());
                           }
                           else
                           {
                              //File end.
                           }
                        }
                    }
                }
```